# Trying to compare strings

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare two strings with IP address stored inside the `map<string,IPHost> Address_list`. I am new to C++ and I think I did something wrong with header and implementation file. This is what I write so far. When I compile it, it says:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'IPHost::IPHost()`
```

Can someone guide me how to fix it?

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef IPHOST_H
#define IPHOST_H
#include <iostream>
class IPHost
{
    public:
        IPHost(int ip0, int ip1, int ip2, int ip3);

        bool checkIP(const IPHost&) const;

    private:
        int one;
        int two;
        int three;
        int four;
};

#endif
```

This is my implementation file:

```
#include "IPHost.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

IPHost::IPHost(int ip0, int ip1, int ip2, int ip3 )
{
    ip0=one;
    ip1=two;
    ip2=three;
    ip3=four;
}



bool IPHost::checkIP(const IPHost& h)const
{
    if(one == h.one && two == h.two && three == h.three && four == h.four)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "IPHost.h"

using namespace std;
int main
{
   map<string, IPHost> Address_list;
   Address_list["google.com"]=IPHost(74,125,225,20);
   Address_list["m.twitter.com"]=IPHost(199,16,156,43);

   if (Address_list["google.com"].checkIP(Address_list["m.twitter.com"]))
   {
      cout << "Two IP address are the same.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Two IP address do not match.\n";
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say this:

```
Address_list["google.com"]=IPHost(74,125,225,20);
```

`std::map::operator[]` is default-constructing an `IPHost` object, which it then returns by reference, then you copy-assign a temporary `IPHost` to this object.  The compiler is complaining because `IPHost` has no default constructor, and so the `std::map::operator[]` method implementation cannot be instantiated.

(This is required because the syntax does not allow `std::map` to know what value you are trying to assign; all it knows is that you want to access the key `"google.com"`, which might not exist, so it needs to create an `IPHost` object so you can assign it a value.  Default construction is the only sane choice.)

You need to provide a default constructor for `IPHost` if you want to use this syntax:

```
public: IPHost();

// Later...

IPHost::IPHost() : one(0), two(0), three(0), four(0) { }
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::map::insert` instead, which does not require the value type to be default-constructible because you are directly giving an `IPHost` object to use as the value.

```
Address_list.insert(std::pair<std::string const, IPHost>(
    "google.com", IPHost(74,125,225,20)));
```

If you have access to C++11, you could make this operation a bit more efficient and less verbose by using `std::map::emplace`:

```
Address_list.emplace("google.com", IPHost(74,125,225,20));
```

---

Note that `insert` and `emplace` *will not* replace the value if the key is already found!  If that is desired you should inspect the return value from the `insert` or `emplace` call, which contains an iterator to the element in the map and a bool indicating if it did create the item.  In this way, they are not exactly identical to the `a[b] = c` syntax in terms of how they affect the contents of the map.

If you commonly find yourself attempting to set a value in a map without regard for whether the key already exists, I would strongly suggest adding a default constructor to `IPHost` as it will make the simpler `a[b] = c` syntax possible and prevent you from having to write the more complex if-item-already-exists-then-update-it-instead case.

Comment: Thank you cdhowie. Your explanation is very helpful and totally solved my problem.

Comment: @GublacK No problem. Please note the addition to my answer regarding the behavior of `insert` and `emplace` in the event that the key you are trying to insert already exists. If you don't know this detail then it may catch you off-guard.